# How to return in Java 8 a Map with one entry removed

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap

Using Java 8 I have a `Map<String, String>` and I want to use a method of one of the standard libraries to **return** a `Map` with a specified entry removed.

So essentially I'm looking for a way to achieve **just by a function call or by function concatenation** the following (hypothetical) method of Map:

```
Map<String, String> removed(String key) {
    this.remove(key);
    return this;
}
```

The whole thing would help me to convert a `Map` of a `Bean` into a pretty string in one line

Comment: Why would you want to do it all in one line?

Comment: Why do not you call your `removed()` method above?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto well I don't have the method - and for *one* call it is a bit too much to define it

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well, as a pretty toString function I have at the moment this: `return super.toString() + ":\n" + StringUtils.join(BeanUtils.describe(this).entrySet().iterator(), "\n");` but I want to remove the superfluous entry "class". So it would be nice to keep it one expression.

Comment: It seems you and I have different definitions of "nice".

Comment: So, what's your objection to writing a method that evaluates this thing you're trying to return?

Comment: You're wasting valuable development time with this kind of micro-coding. There's no "pretty" way to do it in the standard library, so you'll end up doing it in a (in your opinion) non-pretty way. However you can go for a straight-forward approach, or you can end up with a "clever and nice" solution that will make programmers who end up looking at your code shake their fists in anger.

Comment: I was curious, whether there is an simple way in Java 8 (which has a lot more functional additions) - I think the question is perfectly valid, but maybe there is just no easy answer.

Comment: if you can guarantee that the Map is mutable, why not create a static method `removed` and then just call `remove` inside it and return the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that does not modify the input map could look like this.

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals(other))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Yes, I do not think it can get easier than that.

Comment: I would punch anyone who claimed  this is a "simple" and "nice" solution.

Comment: @Kayaman yeah, missed the "!" - thanks! This is Java so things are neither simple nor nice. A "remove" method returning a new instance would simply be a nice and clean solution but Java Collections API makes it hard to do.

Comment: Pretty cool answer! Thanks! Though I do have to agree with @Kayaman that this is not very concise or even clear. - But I didn't ask for clarity...

Comment: @halloleo thanks! If you could use Vavr in your code, that would be simply equal to `Map<String, String> map = source.remove(other)`

Comment: Or with Guava `Maps.filterKeys(map, k -> !k.equals("class"))`. I strongly recommend using tried and tested additional libraries before going with raw `stream()`. If you ever have to maintain legacy code, you'll appreciate the readability.

Comment: @Kayaman after so `much` java-8 in our code base (years) , it's really hard to accept your opinion - I tend to read java-8 code with streams much faster the the previous way

Comment: @Kayaman: any solution that searches linearly through the keys of a map for a predicate that is just equality, in other words, would be `O(1)` (`HashMap`) or `O(log n)` (`TreeMap`) when using a appropriate `Map` operation (`map.remove(obj)`), is unacceptable.

Comment: @Holger from a performance point yes, but the question was about simplicity. Considering the issue was with a `toString()` method, any performance effect would be minimal compared to what for example `BeanUtils.describe(this)` does.

Comment: @Eugene that depends on the code of course. But when you see people start using `forEach()` instead of `for-each` just because they think "Oh, Java is a functional language now", you end up with code using new functionality just for the sake of it. People come up with weird constructs just because they think that you're not supposed to use `for(int i = 0;i < x.size(); i++)` anymore. Java is still not a functional language. If you want to write only functional code, do it in a language that's meant for it.

Comment: @Kayaman: indeed, if that context wasn’t buried in a comment, but rather part of the question, it was clear immediately, that we have a linear operation anyway, so filtering *while producing the string* would be appropriate. Then, the `remove` method the OP asks for in the question would be obsolete…

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do, is to implement a `toString()` method skipping the `"class"` property, you could do that straight-forwardly without manipulating the `Map`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return BeanUtils.describe(this).entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("class"))
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", super.toString()+":\n", ""));
}
```

But to me, not being able to exclude the `class` property in the first place, looks like an unfortunate omission. Consider:

```
public class MyBeanUtils {
    public static Map<String,Object> describe(Object o) {
        try {
            return describe(o, Introspector.getBeanInfo(o.getClass()));
        } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
    public static Map<String,Object> describe(Object o, Class<?> stopClass) {
        try {
            return describe(o, Introspector.getBeanInfo(o.getClass(), stopClass));
        } catch (IntrospectionException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }
    private static Map<String,Object> describe(Object o, BeanInfo beanInfo) {
        Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
        for(PropertyDescriptor fd: beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            if(fd.getReadMethod()!=null) try {
                map.put(fd.getName(), fd.getReadMethod().invoke(o));
            } catch(IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex){}
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

Now, by specifying `Object.class` as stop class, we exclude its properties, which is exactly the `class` property defined by `Object.getClass()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return MyBeanUtils.describe(this, Object.class).entrySet().stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", super.toString()+":\n", ""));
}
```

This even enables another opportunity. If we assume that `super.toString()` already cares for all properties of the super class hierarchy, we can specify our own superclass as stop class to only add properties defined in our class:

```
public class BeanExample extends JButton {
    String foo = "some string";
    int bar = 42;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MyBeanUtils.describe(this, getClass().getSuperclass()).entrySet().stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n", super.toString()+":\n", ""));
    }
}
```

→

```
BeanExample[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@b1bc7ed,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=2,left=14,bottom=2,right=14],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]:
bar=42
foo=some string
```

Comment: I agree, what `org.apache.commons.beanutils` does, is not what I expected either, but that's what it does (and I don't want to rewrite it for me purposes). Anyway, I like your approach to avoid the map altogether - unfortunately I didn't phrase my question like that...

Comment: @halloleo: the first approach isn’t avoiding the map, it is just avoiding to modify it. The second approach is also meant to demonstrate, how little effort is needed to support it, as `Introspector` already provides the stop class feature. So it’s also worth asking the Apache `BeanUtils` maintainers whether they can add this feature.